# Arduino - non-blocking pulsing

Tags: arduino

I am using an Arduino to control a couple of [Victor 884's](http://www.vexrobotics.com/victor-speed-controller.html).

After some research, I found out you need to send it some pulses of different durations to make it go (I have no clue what the right terminology here is).

To control it, you do the following.

```
Stop = 1.5 ms on and 0.5 ms off.
Forward Full Power = 2 ms on and 0 ms off
Backward Full Power = 1 ms on and 1 ms off
```

So to make the motor stop, I could use some code like this.

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(1500);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(500);
}
```

The problem is, this code is blocking so I can't do anything without messing of the time.
The solution is to get rid of the delay statement.

I was able to make a non-blocking version based on the [BlinkWithoutDelay](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) example.

The problem arises when I try control 3-4 Victors. I tried the copy, paste, rename-with-some-numbers-tacked-on method, but the code quickly gets messy.

So my question is, how should I do this? Should I write some classes to handle it for me (a pain since I have no clue how to write a class in C++) or should I look into using the Arduino's timers to achieve my goal.

Comment: I would go with interrupts - they are not blocking and the handler will be invoked using the hardware timers so you will have exact timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both the Timer library and create your own classes to keep things clean. Instead of classes you can also create an additional .pde/.ino file containing functions to drive the 884s.

If you are running windows then grab a copy of Visual Studio Professional and the Arduino Plugin. It has an option to create new Cpp file which automatically creates a class for you. http://www.visualmicro.com

Classes are quite easy when you see one working. Another alternative is to create your own library to handle the 884 code but that is more complicated.

Edit: If you are going to learn more C++ then follow the comment by Pawel above. Pawel is right interrupts are best especially if using `microSeconds` which I missed the first time I read your request.

Comment: I think I am going to take the opportunity to learn more c++.

Comment: I will include the link to the library when i'm done(This question is already on the first page of google for the search "arduino victor 884")

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you might want to learn about pulse width modulation aka PWM: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PWM